# Fedora Dual Monitor - One Workspace Per Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, fedora-11, workspace

I recently upgraded to Fedora 11 and plugged in a second monitor for my at-home workstation. However, I'd really like to figure out a way to use each monitor as its own workspace that I can move back and forth between with my mouse.

Right now, a single workspace covers both monitors so when I open an application, it opens it on the left monitor only, regardless of which monitor the link to the application is on. Except for the Terminal link, oddly enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar (not identical) problem to yours and managed to find a solution. Maybe it will be helpful to someone anyway.

- I assume that you've got the two monitors working and that the single desktop is extended across both (i.e. such that you can drag apps onto the second monitor).
- Right clicking on the GNOME panel at the top or bottom of the screen gives the option of 'New Panel'. Click this and drag the new panel onto the second monitor.
- Now right click on the new panel and select 'Add to panel'. Scroll down to the bottom of the resulting list and select 'Window List'.

Now you have a list of windows on your second monitor. The new window list will only show the windows which are sitting on the extended part of the desktop, while the window list on your main monitor will similarly only show windows residing there.

All these windows are running in the same workspace, but this technique 'approximates' the one-workspace-per-monitor that you originally asked for. With this setup you can easily drag windows from one monitor to the other and, naturally, copying/pasting works properly too.

Answer (score 1):

Geez, a chance to actually help someone!

If you have a nVidia chip then use the nVidia package from the rpm-nonfree repo (kmod-nvidia) and configure it to your liking with the GUI setup tool.  This is exactly what I do and have done for years.  I suspect it is similar for ATI but I cannot testify to that.  If you need a more detailed explanation for nVidia I will be glad to supply it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the direct answer to your question, but... this may be useful:
If I double click on a link on the left side, and the mouse pointer stays at the left side it opens at the left side, however, if I do the same, but the mouse pointer is in the right side, the app opens in the right side (where the mouse pointer is positioned at).

Best,
Pablo, UTEP